# How to wrap a JS library with a function and put it into a namespace?

Tags: javascript, oop, namespaces, global-variables, encapsulation

I have a **Payment Gateway API wrapper** in **JavaScript**.

But It has been designed badly.

It uses **163 global (window) objects**.

What I want to do is

**get all the global objects generated by the API wrapper**

and **put them all in one object named "PG".**

So I can use its method by

```
PG.methodName()
```

and get variable by

```
PG.variableName
```

#### How can I accomplish this with JavaScript?

#### Or is there other ways to load scripts with namespace?

---

Here is the problematic JS Library: [See Gist](https://gist.github.com/inspiredjw/1b1c79f84608861f5266)

Comment: Wow, that´s a lot of bold text! Well, how does the code look? Could you include it?

Comment: @Stefan I edited my question to include the JS Library

Comment: is your library adding things on `window.` or is it "just" missing `var`s ?

Comment: @user1737909 This is not my library :( 
but it is using `vars` in `global scope`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dummy javascript object and add functions and variables to it like this:

```
var PG = PG || {};
PG.methodName = apiMethodName;
PG.variable = variableName;
```

This approach will create their dublicates within `PG` scope while leaving original functions in `window` scope. In order to move them from global scope you will have to modify api scripts themselves, which may be not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures).

Use an "[Immediately-Invoked Function Expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)" (also known as "Self-Executing Anonymous Function") to wrap and execute your code;

```
(function( window, document, NS, undefined ){

  NS.variableName = "string value";
  NS.methodName = function() {};

  function myFunction() { alert('within closure'); };

}( window, window.document, (window.NS = window.NS || {}) ));
```

You can then access `NS` from outside the closure but not the function `myFunction` that´s restricted to the closure scope.

Yes, you can rename `NS` to `PG` or even `PayGate` :)

Comment: if you want to use a API to manage your namepaces you should check out the namespace.js from mckoss: [link](https://github.com/mckoss/namespace)

Comment: Yeah, I´m familiar with `namespace.js`. It´s great for creating larger namespaces but not really neccessary in this case.